# How to sort a array data with another array order?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am searching any times, but I am not finding any solution exactly what I want. My question is How can I sort array with another array that defined the array order.

Suppose-

```
const array1 = [
    {
        name: "1"
    },
    {
        name: "2"
    },
    {
        name: "3"
    }
]

const array2 = ["3", "1"]
```

I need to sort array1 by following

```
const array = [
    {
        name: "3"
    },
    {
        name: "1"
    },
    {
        name: "2"
    }
]
```

Here, we can see array2 values are now top of array1. I want this function.

I already tried, but gives wrong result-

```
const sortMarkets = (array: ArrayTypes[], sortArray: string[]) => {
  return [...array].sort(
    (a, b) => sortArray.indexOf(a.name) - sortArray.indexOf(b.name)
  )
}

console.log(sortMarkets(array, ag));
```

It gives me-

```
[{
  "name": "2"
}, {
  "name": "1"
}, {
  "name": "3"
}]
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get another value for unknow items. In this case, a large value moves the item to the end.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: "1" }, { name: "2" }, { name: "3" }],
    ag = ["3", "1"],
    sortMarkets = (array, sortArray) => {
        const getOrder = name => (sortArray.indexOf(name) + 1) || Number.MAX_VALUE;
        return [...array].sort((a, b) => getOrder(a.name) - getOrder(b.name));
    };

console.log(sortMarkets(array, ag));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Comparing the `.indexOf` with the value the other array isn't enough because there are *two* criteria to sort by - one, for elements in the other array to come on top of the others, and two, for those top elements to be sorted according to their position in the other array. Add another check first to see whether the items being compared should come in different sections (on the top or the bottom).

```js
const array1 = [
    {
        name: "1"
    },
    {
        name: "2"
    },
    {
        name: "3"
    }
];
const array2 = ["3", "1"];
array1.sort((a, b) =>
  (array2.includes(b.name) - array2.includes(a.name))
  || (array2.indexOf(a.name) - array2.indexOf(b.name))
);
console.log(array1);
```

To make TypeScript happy, cast the booleans to numbers before subtracting.

```
(Number(array2.includes(b.name)) - Number(array2.includes(a.name)))
```

Comment: Working but gives me typescript error

Comment: Includes gives me true of false. then how, it done a arithmetic operations

Comment: Cast the booleans to numbers before subtracting